# How to Skip Content from a tag <span class=""> </span> while regex search?

Tags: html, regex, pattern-matching, nsregularexpression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I have a string which is html like this

```
<html>
  <div>
      <p>this is sample content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
      <p>this is another sample</p>
      <span class="test">this sample should not caught</span>
      <div>
       this is another sample
      </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

now i want to search the word `sample` from this string, here i should not get the "sample" which is inside the `<span>...</span>`

I want this to be done using regex, i tried a lot but i cant do it, any help is greatful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless this piece of html is always the same, it's a bad idea to parse html/xml with a regular expression. [Here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg).

Comment: @acme i agree with u, but how to solve my problem.. is there any idea to solve this..

Comment: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite brittle and fails if there can be nested `span` tags. If you don't have those, try

```
(?s)sample(?!(?:(?!</?span).)*</span>)
```

This matches `sample` only if the next following `span` tag (if any) is not a closing tag.

**Explanation:**

```
(?s)          # Switch on dot-matches-all mode
sample        # Match "sample".
(?!           # only if it's not followed by the following regex:
 (?:          #  Match...
  (?!</?span) #   (unless we're at the start of a span tag)
  .           #   any character
 )*           #  any number of times.
 </span>      #  Match a closing span tag.
)             # End of lookahead
```

To match `sample` only if it's neither within a `span` nor a `p`, you can use

```
(?s)sample(?!(?:(?!</?span).)*</span>)(?!(?:(?!</?p).)*</p>)
```

But all this depends entirely on tags being unnested (i. e., no two tags of the same kind may be nested) and correctly balanced (which often isn't given with `p` tags).

Comment: hi its working fine, can i skip more than one tag using this regex, i.e., if i want to skip content from both <span> and <p> tag, how to do it using this..

Comment: Just add another lookahead. See my edit.

Comment: make the closing tag / as optional in look ahead, i think this will solve nested tags prob... sample(?!(?:(?!</?span).)*</?span>)(?!(?:(?!</?p).)*</?p>)

Comment: No, it won't. Then it won't match at all if a `span` or `p` tag follows in the string. If it does, it's because you need to switch on dot-matches-all mode for this regex to work with multiline strings. I had forgotten to make this explicit. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: no, its matching correctly only... just check once, i tested using "expresso"

Comment: As I said, you need to turn on dot-matches-all mode (in expresso and otherwise). Otherwise this regex fails on tags that span multiple lines. Take your pick :)

Comment: hi.. its working perctly fine for me... the only prob i was facing is, if i was using the large string then it taking more time to capture the matches, can u suggest anything related to this problem?

Comment: Yes, this is to be expected - the nested lookaheads are rather inefficient. That's probably unavoidable - which is another reason why HTML should be parsed instead of regexed.

Comment: which parser can i use for this situation..

Comment: Perhaps you can find a workable solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parse+html+objective-c